# Progress bars in foundation zurb are not stacking?

Tags: html, css, progress-bar, zurb-foundation, stacked

The Foundation Zurb Stacked progress bars is not working i need example in code-pen to use. 
here is the code that i tried and it didn't work.

```
    <div class="progress large-6 radius round">
                      <span class="meter secondary" style="width: 20%"></span>
                      <span class="meter  alert " style="width: 20%"></span>
                      <span class="meter  success" style="width: 20%"></span></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately even though an example of the stacked progress bar is in their docs at http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/progress_bars.html, they have not published a new release since then, so the latest release (5.5.2) doesn't contain the necessary code.  That said it's an easy change to apply yourself:

https://github.com/zurb/foundation/commit/ece27e875243c32a620f7caa219a0b9718b47d60